# Android Studio - Library module inside library module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to setup a project in this way:

```
MainModule -> LibraryModule1 -> LibraryModule2
↓                                      ↑
----------------------------------------
```

Every module 'sits' in a different git repository.
**MainModule** git repository includes **LibraryModule1** as a submodule.
**LibraryModule1** git repository includes **LibraryModule2** as a submodule.

The **Android** perspective:

In summary (from the end):
**LibraryModule2** is an android library (com.android.library)
**LibraryModule1** is an android library (com.android.library) which has **LibraryModule2** as module dependency
**MainModule** is an android application (com.android.application) which has **LibraryModule1** as module dependency
(**MainModule** should 'know' about **LibraryModule2** too)

The main goal is to to be able to include **LibraryModule1** in other applications too.

Here's the gradle files:

**LibraryModule1** settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', include ':library2'
project(':library2').projectDir = new File('path_to_library_2')
```

**LibraryModule1** build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    api project(path: ':library2')
}
```

**MainModule** settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':library1'
project(':library1').projectDir = new File('path_to_library_1')
```

**MainModule** build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    implementation project(':library1')
}
```

When trying to sync gradle, a problem occurs:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':library1'.
> Project with path ':library2' could not be found in project ':library1'.

Is there a way to solve it without specifically include **LibraryModule2** in **MainModule**?